# SQL query to retrieve the list of all the employees from database

Tags: sql

For each department, list all the employees who are working in the department with the employee's first and last name and first and last name of his or her immediate supervisor. Include all the departments and all the employees (including who do not have any supervisor). List the result in the order of each department number and first name of each employee.

My work so far is

```
SELECT 
    d.Dnumber, d.Dname, e.Fname, e.Lname, s.Fname, s.Lname
FROM 
    Company.Employee e
JOIN 
    Company.Department d ON e.Dno = d.Dnumber
LEFT JOIN 
    Company.Employee s ON e.Super_ssn = s.Ssn
ORDER BY 
    d.Dnumber, e.Fname;
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Please tag the only `DBMS` that you are really using.

Comment: This is my first time using this platform so, I don't know that much about tagging. Thank you will keep this on mind next time.

Comment: @MPsir What results are you getting from this query and what are your expected results?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product **are** you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I would recommend reading the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for tips on asking good questions which people will be able and willing to answer for you. Also, the page on [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is very helpful. In this specific example, it would be useful for you to show the DDL for your tables, some example data from those tables and your expected output from that example data. This will mean more people will be willing and able to help with answering your question.

Comment: I'm using a sql-server and the result from the above code give me the list of all employees working in that department with their name and supervisor sorted by each department number and name but I need the include the all the employees who do not have any supervisor also.